# Remove last character from json output using JQ

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have a json that looks like this:

```
{ 
  "HostedZones": [
      {
          "ResourceRecordSetCount": 2,
          "CallerReference": "test20150527-2",
          "Config": {
              "Comment": "test2",
              "PrivateZone": true
          },
          "Id": "/hostedzone/Z119WBBTVP5WFX",
          "Name": "dev.devx.company.services."
      },
      {
          "ResourceRecordSetCount": 2,
          "CallerReference": "test20150527-1",
          "Config": {
              "Comment": "test",
              "PrivateZone": true
          },
          "Id": "/hostedzone/Z3P5QSUBK4POTI",
          "Name": "test.devx.company.services."
      }
  ],
  "IsTruncated": false,
  "MaxItems": "100"
}
```

And my goal is to fetch a specific `Name` (in my case it's the `test.devx.company.services`), however the `Name` field contains an extra "`.`" at the end that I'd like to remove from the output.

This is what I have so far:

`jq --raw-output '.HostedZones[] | select(.Name | test("test")?) | (.Name[:-1] | sub("."; ""))'`

The problem with that it is removing the first character from the output also.

So the output currently is: `est.devx.company.services` ([JQ play snippet](https://jqplay.org/s/W3PCQ6C9Z-s))

Not sure what I'm doing wrong :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To always remove the last character, if it contains "test":

```bash
jq '(.HostedZones[].Name | select(contains("test"))) |= .[:-1]'
```

To remove it only if it is a dot:

```bash
jq '(.HostedZones[].Name | select(contains("test"))) |= sub("[.]$"; "")'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but when I try it out it outputs the whole json.. Is there a way to select the output that contains `test` then remove the dot at the end?

Comment: @Fadi Sure, just turn `(…) |= …` into `… | …`.

Comment: Ah! Thanks for the help! Your answer is also much more elegant than mine! xD

Comment: Since `.` is the glob character in a regex, you have to escape it somehow, as per revision.

Comment: @peak Absolutely right, of course. Thank you for spotting it.